# Jenkins pipeline works fine when file is uploaded and errors when it is not

Tags: jenkins, file-upload, error-handling, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

The name of plugin `[Stashed File Parameter][1]` is `uploadfile` [File Parameter | Jenkins plugin] https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-parameters/

I use this plugin to upload files using Jenkins pipeline.

The pipeline works fine / successfully when I upload any file; but fails with error when no files are uploaded.

My Jenkins declarative pipeline is as below.

```
pipeline {

    agent {

        node {

            label 'Ansible_host'

        }

    }

    stages {

        stage('Precheck') {

            steps {

                unstash 'uploadfile'


                script{

                    if ( uploadfile_FILENAME != "" )

                    {

                        sh "mv uploadfile '$uploadfile_FILENAME'"

                    }

                if ( uploadfile_FILENAME != "" )

                {

                    echo "File is uploaded from localhost"  

                }

                else

                {

                    echo "File is uploaded from $source_host"

                }

                }

                sh "echo Im from Jenkins>/tmp/jenkinsmoht.txt"
             

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Error when no files are uploaded:

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 5243a730-ce5f-4f9e-af0b-9e3a99f84ef1

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: uploadfile_FILENAME for class: groovy.lang.Binding

                       at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)

                       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:285)

                       at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:375)

                       at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:379)

                       at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:355)

                       at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:355)

                       at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:355)

                       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)

                       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)

                       at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:15)

                       at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)

                       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:73)

                       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)

                       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:65)

                       at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor261.invoke(Unknown Source)

                       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

                       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)

                       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)

                       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)

                       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)

                       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:152)

                       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:146)

                       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)

                       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)

                       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:146)

                       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)

                       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)

                       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:187)

                       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:420)

                       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)

                       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:294)

                       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)

                       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

                       at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)

                       at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)

                       at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)

                       at jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)

                       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)

                       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

                       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)

                       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)

                       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Finished: FAILURE
```

In the earlier versions of Jenkins, this error was not seen.

Can you please suggest how can I avoid this error when no files are uploaded using the plugin?

Comment: I might be able to help you! I just need to know where your variable `uploadfile_FILENAME` is declared. Is it in the unstash?

Comment: @fakolours yes. Basically, I pasted by entire pipeline code without removing any single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the plugin documentation, I understand that `uploadfile` is a build parameter of type `stashedFile` defined in the job configuration page and it returns the original filename as the environment variable `uploadfile_FILENAME`.

Since your script already works when there is a file to upload, you can rewrite the if conditions as:

```
if (env.uploadfile_FILENAME) {
    sh "mv uploadfile '$uploadfile_FILENAME'"
    echo "File is uploaded from localhost" 
} else {
    echo "File is uploaded from $source_host"
}
```

In this case, when there is no file to upload, the value of `env.uploadfile_FILENAME` will be `null` or an empty string and the if condition will return `false` without throwing the `No such property` error.